# Discrepancy in node values of a single tree in scikit-learn's random forest

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, decision-tree

I built a random forest model using the `scikit-learn` package and visualized the first tree. I cannot understand why some nodes' “value” do not equal the average.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn import tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

X = np.array(list(range(1, 11))).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array([4.50, 4.75, 4.91, 5.34, 5.80, 7.05, 7.90, 8.23, 8.70, 9.00])

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=3, max_depth=2)
rf.fit(X, y)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6, 3), dpi=450)

tree.plot_tree(rf[0], filled=True, precision=6)

plt.show()
```

As the following figure shows, the circled node has a "value" of `8.88`, however I think it should be: `(8.70+9.00)/2=8.85`. In reality, I have checked many times, and it returns similar results.

But, using `DecisionTreeRegressor` function to build a Decision Tree, it has no this matter.

[image: See figure here]

Please explain the confusing results.

Comment: It is indeed weird that even considering bootstrapping there is no combination of two samples whose average is 8.88